# How to do UITextField's leftView in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder, uitextfield

Looking at **UITextField** item in **Interface Builder**, cannot see any way to set **leftView** property. Would like the put there an icon to show user that this is place for text input.

```
The overlay view displayed on the left side of the text field.
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *leftView
```

Can it be set using IB at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean UITextField? It looks like you cannot do that in IB. Instead, somewhere in your view controller's -viewDidLoad set both leftView and leftViewMode properties.

Comment: Sorry, yes: it was really UITextField! I was afraid of that, but got to do what you got to do. Will try in code, thanx!

Comment: Just to report the results: I added a custom UIImage in XIB in location of expected leftView and setup that in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Works just great!